# @font-face font not loading without www in url

Tags: css, font-face

I have an issue when I load my site http://example.com (without www) the fonts are not loaded.

After clicking on a link from there the next page loads properly and fonts load but that is because the www is added to the url.

The rest of the css is being loaded fine it only appears to be the font that is not being loaded when the www is not included in the url.

here is the css for the font face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerregular';
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#allerregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Do you see anything related wrong in browser console?

Comment: Just checked and yes looks like there is an issue: Font from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: This is a server configuration issue. You need to point the www address to the non-www address. Your problem has nothing to do with the @font-face declaration.

Comment: It's mostly Firefox related I guess, I'm sure you'll find plenty of results by googling that error.

Comment: yup server configuration issue

Comment: The server was setup to allow both with and without www. I guess that caused the issue.